# Capture and show image from camera2 API, Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-camera2

I have been following a tutorial on how to get a camera preview on a fragment to show on my app, I am new to kotlin but have been programming in Swift for 2 years. Is there a way to get an image from the preview and show it in another image view.

I created an image view called imageGotCont and this is where I want to place the images I have a button in my main activity so when I press it I need a function that gets an image fromt the preview and places it in the image view.

Below is the fragment.

```
class FragmentCameraPreview : Fragment() {


    private val MAX_DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1280
    private val MAX_DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 720
    private lateinit var captureSession: CameraCaptureSession
    private lateinit var captureRequestBuilder: CaptureRequest.Builder
    private lateinit var imageSize: Size
    private lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice


    private val deviceStateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "camera device opened")
            if (camera != null) {
                cameraDevice = camera
                previewSession()
            }
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "camera device disconnected")
            camera?.close()
        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice?, error: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "camera device error")
            this@FragmentCameraPreview.activity?.finish()
        }

    }
    private lateinit var backgroundThread: HandlerThread
    private lateinit var backgroundHandler: Handler

    private val cameraManager by lazy {
        activity?.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager

    }


    companion object {
        private val TAG = FragmentCameraPreview::class.qualifiedName
        const val REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 100
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = FragmentCameraPreview()
    }

    private val surfaceListner = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
        override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(surface: SurfaceTexture?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture?) = Unit

        override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture?): Boolean = true

        override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture?, width: Int, height: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Tony texture surface width: $width height: $height")
            openCamera()
        }

    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
    private fun checkCameraPermission() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(activity!!, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "APP has camera permission")
            connectCamera()
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                activity!!,
                getString(R.string.camera_request_rationale),
                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION,
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        startBackgroundThread()
        if (previewTextureView.isAvailable)
            openCamera()
        else
            previewTextureView.surfaceTextureListener = surfaceListner
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        closeCamera()
        stopBackgroundThread()
        super.onPause()
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera_preview, container, false)


        return myInflatedView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        checkCameraPermission()
    }

    private fun <T> cameraCharacteristics(cameraId: String, key: CameraCharacteristics.Key<T>): T {
        val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        return when (key) {
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING -> characteristics.get(key)
            CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP -> characteristics.get(key)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Key not recognized")
        }
    }

    private fun cameraId(lens: Int): String {
        var deviceId = listOf<String>()

        try {
            val cameraIdList = cameraManager.cameraIdList

            deviceId = cameraIdList.filter { lens == cameraCharacteristics(it, CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) }
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }
        return deviceId[0]
    }

    private fun connectCamera() {
        val deviceID = cameraId(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        Log.d(TAG, "deviceID: $deviceID")
        try {
            cameraManager.openCamera(deviceID, deviceStateCallback, backgroundHandler)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Open camera device interrupted while opening")
        }
    }

    private fun startBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread = HandlerThread("CameraKotlin").also { it.start() }
        backgroundHandler = Handler(backgroundThread.looper)
    }

    private fun stopBackgroundThread() {
        backgroundThread.quitSafely()
        try {
            backgroundThread.join()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun previewSession() {
        val surfaceTexture = previewTextureView.surfaceTexture
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(MAX_DISPLAY_WIDTH, MAX_DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)

        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
            Arrays.asList(surface),
            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession?) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "creating capture session failed")
                }

                override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession?) {
                    if (session != null) {
                        captureSession = session
                        captureRequestBuilder.set(
                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                        )
                        captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                    }
                }

            }, null
        )
    }

    private fun closeCamera() {
        if (this::captureSession.isInitialized)
            captureSession.close()
        if (this::cameraDevice.isInitialized)
            cameraDevice.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still have the tutorial you used?